# How do I find out invalid HTML that my browser chose to ignore?

Tags: html, internet-explorer, firefox, browser, firebug

For example, in the following HTML ...

```
<form name="outerform">
  <input type="text" name="outer1"/>
  <input type="text" name="outer2"/>

  <div>
    <form name="innerform" method="post" action="#">
      <input type="text" name="inner1"/>
    </form>
  </div>
</form>
```

Firefox will simply throw away the *innerform* `<form>` tag, since forms cannot be nested.

I ran into this while patching some legacy code.  Someone had placed a `<form>` tag covering almost the entire `body` content.  When I added my own, more localized `<form>`, Firefox stripped out the inner tag and my submits were going to the outer form.  Since I was doing some jQuery processing to create my submit URL, I thought it was my error.  I realized the problem after viewing the rendered HTML in Firebug's HTML tab.

If the browser, or Firebug had a tab for "ignored HTML", or some such method I would have picked it out immediately.  I can't simply do a View-Source and paste it into the W3C's web-based validation service for the following reasons:

1. For security reasons, the development computer I'm on is not connected to the public Internet.
2. Firebug's HTML tab shows the rendered HTML, so the invalid HTML tag has already been removed.

Finally, the editor (Eclipse) is usually where I catch bugs like this. But we use a lot of included files and the Tiles framework, so you only see a fragment of the final HTML page at a time.

Comment: Firefox's view-source doesn't show the rendered HTML; if I put something like your testcase it shows both `<form>` tags...

Comment: Thanks, I have corrected that in the question. I meant Firebug's HTML tab, not view-source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found my solution. Thanks to Boris Zbarsky's comment for pointing me in the right direction.  The view-source shows the downloaded HTML, but the Firebug DOM inspector shows the rendered HTML (I was mistaking the two in the question).  Solution:

1. Do a view-source and save the file (File 1)
2. Open Firebug's DOM inspector, right-click the top-level element `<html>`, Copy HTML, and save to file (File 2)
3. Use a diff tool to compare the two files.  In a graphical diff tool, File 2 will show gaps where the browser ignored/removed HTML.

Reformatting the HTML in the two files might make diffing easier.

Answer (score 0):

If it's invalid, there's no way of knowing how the browser will react; thus anything that is listed as broken in [an HTML Validator](http://validator.nu/) should probably be fixed.

You can validate HTML offline; for example, there's a [plugin for Coda](http://www.chipwreck.de/blog/software/coda-php/) that I use that validates HTML offline.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the wget tool, it is quite practical to get an exact copy of the HTML your server generates. Even the View Source feature does not always show you exactly what was downloaded (maybe it is now, but I spent hours looking at "valid" code there, when the server was not doing it right.)

You can get wget for MS-Windows from the mingw tools on SourceForge.net. Under Linux, it is likely already installed, if not just search for it in your repositories.